# Create private image (from VMDK or another format) in Google Compute Engine

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

Hello anyone help me to create an private image in Google Compute Engine using Java language. Using that image I want to create an instance.

I use Compute client to create an instance with public image in target cloud below is sample code-

```
Instance instance = new instance().setName(server.getName());
Image image = client.images().get("debian-cloud",role.getName()).execute();
AttachedDiskInitializeParams iParams = new AttachedDiskInitializeParams();            
iParams.setDiskName(server.getName()).setDiskSizeGb(10L).setSourceImage(image.getSelfLink());
AttachedDisk attDisk = new AttachedDisk().setBoot(true).setType("PERSISTENT").setAutoDelete(Boolean.FALSE).setMode("READ_WRITE").setInitializeParams(iParams);
instance.setDisks(new ArrayList<AttachedDisk>Arrays.asList(attDisk)));
```

Now I want to create an instance using my private image. How can I create that image using rest. I have an image so I want to upload it to Google Compute Engine and create instance using that image, but I am unable to figure out way to create image in Google Compute Engine after referring the Google Compute Engine API.

Comment: Please expand your question and add more details as to what you're trying to do. This is too generic.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "using Java language"? You can create images using REST api, command line or dashboard, i think it's somewhat independent to the language.

According to  [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images) ,

> Private images
>
> By default, any images you create are private images that are only accessible by the project where the image originated. You can create a new private image from an existing root persistent disk or you can build a new private image from scratch.

You just can't create public images unless you're from Google, open-source communities, and third-party vendors...=)

So if you want to create private images using your language, you just have to call the REST api inside your program.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using a Java Client which ultimately uses REST API. From the google doc it says you can build a new image from scratch just trying to find out a way to do this. I am able to do this using command line.

Comment: @pkumar, if you want to create an image from your own images(rawdisk  maybe?) using REST api, refer this: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/images/insert

Comment: fyi, I think you have to upload your disk images to the google cloud storage first. I didn't tried this but it seems that google  accepts disk images only from the cloud storage, according to the doc.